# How to set discount amount with discount code when create order programmatically?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have created an order pragmatically and invoiced it forcefully to complete order when I check order under sales->order it shows the order completed but discount code always with zero amount.How to show given discount with discounted price on products.

below is my code working fine but need to add discount price with discount code.

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
    $customer->setStore($store);
    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
    $quote->setStore($store);

     $quote->setCustomerEmail($_REQUEST['customerEmail']);
         $addressData = array(
        'firstname' => ' ',
        'lastname' => ' ',
        'street' => ' ',
        'city' => 'NULL',
        'postcode' => 'NULL',
        'telephone' => '123456',
        'country_id' => 'US',
        'region_id' => 12,  );
        $billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($addressData);
        $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($addressData);



    $productIds=array();
    $products=$_REQUEST['productIds'];
    $products=str_replace(array( '[', ']' ), '',$products);
    $productIds=explode(',',$products);
    $quant=$_REQUEST['quantity'];
    $quant=str_replace(array( '[', ']' ), '',$quant);
    $quantities=explode(',',$quant);
    $salesReport=array_combine($productIds,$quantities);

    foreach($salesReport as $ids=>$qty)
    {
        $product1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($ids); /* HTC Touch Diamond */
        $buyInfo1 = array('qty' => $qty);
        $quoteItem=$quote->addProduct($product1, new Varien_Object($buyInfo1));
     }
    $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()
        ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping')
        ->setPaymentMethod('ebs');

    $quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'ebs'));
    $quote->setDiscountAmount('5');
    $quote->setCouponCode("SALE");
    $quote->collectTotals()->save();
    $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
    $service->submitAll();
    $order = $service->getOrder();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, is not that the coupon code is not applied, is that it is applied, on Checkout.

Basically, coupon codes are set in "Cart", not in "Checkout".

To make your script run normally, you have to proceed in more steps.
1 / Add product to your customer's cart.
2/ Apply coupon Code.
3/ Create Order from cart loaded previously with coupon code added before.

Hope it helps.

To Apply coupon code on Cart :

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')
->getQuote()
->setCouponCode('YOUR COUPON CODE HERE')
->collectTotals()
->save();
```